# How do I drag a button on top of an image?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I do not want an image button, I just needs this button in a certain position on an image.

Comment: Do you want to fill the screen with some background image and have one button placed in whichever place you like ?

Comment: No the screen has multiple images, it's for the purpose of the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in relative layout:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Use the marginLeft and marginTop to set specifically where to place the button accordint to the image . The imageview contains your image

Comment: I changed mine to relative layout. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes. Not sure why it's blocking me.

Comment: it is normal. it is a stackoverflow rule

Comment: So I still have a slight problem and I'm trying out all the layouts, but I at least know what to look for. I can figure this out on my own from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout. And insert Image and Button in it. It would be a better approach than Relative Layout.

```
<FrameLayout
....
....
>
<ImageView
....
....
/>
<Button
....
....
/>
</FrameLayout>
```